# "data" attribute gives blank/not woking in IE10

Tags: javascript, html

I am adding a flash thingy on my website and it seems that IE10 cannot accept the "data" attribute for this one because it is giving a blank. This is the code when inspected the HTML element:

```
<div id="gameContainer" style="width: 269px; height: 0px;">
<object width="269" height="100%" id="GameLoader" data="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></object>
</div>
```

These are the line of codes on my JS:

```
function minigames() {
    var flashhtml = $('#gameContainer').find('#GameLoader').html();
    if (flashhtml != null) {
        var d = $('#gameContainer').find('#GameLoader').attr('data');
        $('#minigamesRealistic').find('#gameContainer').html('');
        var flashattr = 'type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="269" height="100%" id="GameLoader" data="' + d + '">';
        $('#gameContainer').html('<object ' + flashattr + '<param name="wmode" value="transparent">' + flashhtml + '</object>');
    } else {
        setTimeout("minigames();", 100);
    }
}
```

I call the function on my master page same page where the container is. What could be the problem with this one? Any help appreciated. Thanks. :)

Comment: Instead of finding the empty data attr - why not just alter it with  jQuery? `$('#GameLoader').attr('data', <your swf link here>);`

Comment: You have a point on that. :)

Comment: btw `.html('')` = `.empty()`

Comment: Please show an actual, testable document. A piece of “inspected” HTML code and a JavaScript function do not constitute anything like that. Functions need to be called to have an effect. The HTML you show has empty value for `data`, so why do you expect it to turn to something else=